# symfony2 classloader cannot be used if path structure is not default

Tags: php, symfony, classloader

looks like symfony2 classloader does not allow different paths for namespaces, anyone has any idea?(except changing the classloader).

```
$loader = new \Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespaces(
  array(
    'Symfony\\Component' => \realpath('/myapp/path' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'vendor' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Symfony2Components')
  )
);
$loader->register(true);


// in other file

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$request = Request::createFromGlobals(); // <-- resolves to : '/myapp/path/vendor/Symfony2Components/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php'
// expected '/myapp/path/vendor/Symfony2Components/HttpFoundation/Request.php'
```

Comment: You have a double backslash between single quotes, that may be the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug. Symfony2 ClassLoader just conforms to the [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md):

> Each namespace separator is converted to a DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR when loading from the file system.

You just define the root path, but all the namespace parts will still be used in the path.

Answer (score 0):

@Maerlyn I also thought about that, but its not, good notice thou.

https://github.com/nimmen/ClassLoader/commit/0881a02d3210fd6376abd3b62f0c665642d310bb
made small changes, now it works like(imo as it should):

register namespaces example:

> name\space => /dir/ectory
>   another\name => /another/dir

\name\space\classname resolves to:

> /dir/ectory/classname.php

\another\name\space\class resolves to:

> /another/dir/space/class.php

hope this will help someone.